# many-to-many OR many-to-one for RNN t+1 prediction

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

When designing RNN's to predict the next time-step ahead, I've come across architectures where you train with say `n` timesteps as input and `n` timesteps as output (at t+1).
input: `(X(1), X(2)...X(n))` 
outputs: `(X(2), X(3)...X(n+1))`. 
So you have a many-to-many architecture - e.g. [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/conv_lstm.py).

I've also seen for the same kind of problems a many-to-one architecture: 
 input:  `(X(1), X(2)...X(n))` 
output: `(X(n+1))`.

My question is, what are the advantages and disadvantages of each? Is one generally favoured? 
I'd presume that since when predicting you already have the timesteps `0 to n` there's no benefit in predicting them and therefore no benefit in including them in your loss fn during training, but maybe it helps set the internal state of the RNN correctly?

Answer (score 2):

If we were not predicting the next item in the sequence, I think that the first method would be best---the second would only be used if there were not labels available for every timestep (e.g., if we were trying to determine the sentiment of a sentence and only had a $+$ or $-$ at the very end).  If we had intermediary sentiment labels, it would be an information loss to omit them.  This seems clear.

I am not sure for the case where we are predicting the next value in a sequence, however.  It might even depend on the data itself: perhaps periodic data does better with the first way, for example.

The gradients are very different, however: (To simplify, suppose that $x^{(t)}$ and the hidden state $h^{(t)}$ are both scalars and ignore the biases.)

The forward equations are:

$h^{(t)}=ux^{(t)}+wh^{(t-1)}$

$y^{(t)}=g(vh^{(t)})$

When we perform [BPTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation_through_time), we must backpropagate through $h^{(t)}$ to access the parameters $u$ and $w$:

---

input: $(x^{(1)}, x^{(2)}...x^{(n)})$

outputs: $(x^{(2)}, x^{(3)}...x^{(n+1)})$.

$\dfrac{\partial{L}}{\partial{h^{(t)}}}=\dfrac{\partial{L}}{\partial{h^{(t+1)}}}\dfrac{\partial{h^{(t+1)}}}{\partial{h^{(t)}}}+\dfrac{\partial{L}}{\partial{y^{(t)}}}\dfrac{\partial{y^{(t)}}}{\partial{h^{(t)}}}$

---

input:  $(x^{(1)}, x^{(2)}...x^{(n)})$

output: $(x^{(n+1)})$

$\dfrac{\partial{L}}{\partial{h^{(t)}}}=\dfrac{\partial{L}}{\partial{h^{(t+1)}}}\dfrac{\partial{h^{(t+1)}}}{\partial{h^{(t)}}}$

---

If the first weight in our network is very wrong, using the second way it will have to be adjusted based on a gradient sent back through every single hidden state in the entire unrolled network $\dfrac{\partial{L}}{\partial{h^{(t+1)}}}\dfrac{\partial{h^{(t+1)}}}{\partial{h^{(t)}}}$.  Using the first way, it would still get $\dfrac{\partial{L}}{\partial{h^{(t+1)}}}\dfrac{\partial{h^{(t+1)}}}{\partial{h^{(t)}}}$, but would also get feedback from the effect of its own output on the loss: $\dfrac{\partial{L}}{\partial{y^{(t)}}}\dfrac{\partial{y^{(t)}}}{\partial{h^{(t)}}}$. So when we have an output at each step (included in the loss), this seems to send more immediate feeback.

The tuning of $v$ may also benefit from more steps.

Comment: thank you, your comment saved my day. I'm working from scratch on an architecture many to one and I got your formula. When I looked online for its correctness, I found everywhere the many to many formula. Because of this, I had started to think that I had done something wrong.